# Using ServiceStack with Full .NET Framework

Tags: servicestack

I am getting some strange dependency errors with ServiceStack when targeting the full .NET Framework like so, csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>Tsl.Example</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="5.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Admin" Version="5.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Admin.Core" Version="5.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Api.Swagger" Version="5.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.Core" Version="1.0.44" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Tsl.Example.Data\Tsl.Example.Data.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Tsl.Example.Model\Tsl.Example.Model.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Tsl.Example.Service\Tsl.Example.Service.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0433  The type 'AppHostBase' exists in both 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'   Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\AppHost.cs   19  Active
Error   CS0115  'AppHost.Configure(Container)': no suitable method found to override    Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\AppHost.cs   39  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'Container' exists in both 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587' Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\AppHost.cs   39  Active
Error   CS1729  'AppHostBase' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\AppHost.cs   29  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'Plugins' does not exist in the current context    Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\AppHost.cs   45  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'Plugins' does not exist in the current context    Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\AppHost.cs   47  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'PostmanFeature' exists in both 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'    Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\AppHost.cs   47  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'Plugins' does not exist in the current context    Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\AppHost.cs   48  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'AdminFeature' exists in both 'ServiceStack.Admin, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack.Admin, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'  Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\AppHost.cs   48  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'Plugins' does not exist in the current context    Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\AppHost.cs   49  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'ValidationFeature' exists in both 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587' Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\AppHost.cs   49  Active
Error   CS0433  The type 'Licensing' exists in both 'ServiceStack.Text, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack.Text, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'   Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\Program.cs   13  Active
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Tsl.Example.AppHost' to 'ServiceStack.AppHostBase' Tsl.Example C:\projects\sandbox\api.example.tso.auth.atalasoft\src\Tsl.Example\Startup.cs   51  Active
```

**Can I a target the full .NET Framework and reference ServiceStack libraries?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run on **classic ASP.NET** or HttpListener you should only reference the main `"ServiceStack.Admin"` packages (i.e. without .Core suffix) which contain both .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework v4.5 builds. In a .NET Framework Application it will use the **.NET v4.5** Framework builds.

If you want to create new **ASP.NET Core** Apps on the .NET Framework you should [reference .Core packages instead](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx#reference-core-packages) which only contains **.NET Standard 2.0** builds to force .NET Framework Applications to use the .NET Standard builds that are required for running in ASP.NET Core Apps.

I strongly recommend starting with one of the [ASP.NET Core .NET Framework Templates](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx) to create a working project with the correct dependencies:

```
$ npm install -g @servicestack/cli

$ dotnet-new web-corefx AcmeNetFx
```

You should **never reference both**, also you can only use the same version number of all packages together, i.e. you can't use the deprecated `ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.Core` package with v5.2.1 assemblies.

`ServiceStack.Api.Swagger` contains the old [v1.2 version of Swagger](http://docs.servicestack.net/swagger-api), you likely want to reference `ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi` instead which implements the [newer Swagger 2.0/Open API specification](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi).